# Create dynamic li tag with text along with span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have a JSON array as follows:

```
var teamDetails=[ 
 { "pType" : "Search Engines", "count" : 5},
 { "pType" : "Content Server", "count" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Search Engines", "count" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Business", "count" : 1,},
 { "pType" : "Internet Services", "count" : 1},
];
```

*I want to create dynamic ul & li tags with JSON data in it*

I want the data to be placed like this:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li>
    ***Here the json ptype value***
    <span class="pull-right">
        <strong>
            <h5>***here json count value***</h5>
        </strong>
    </span>
</li>
</ul>
```

how to get this output dynamically for each data..?

I tried it with this code but couldn't figure out how to append the text li and span tag??

```
var clist=$('ul.list-unstyled')

dataProjectCount.forEach(function(a){
  a.count=a.count+" Projects";
  console.log(a.count);

  var li=$('<li/>').appendTo(clist);
  var aa=$('<span/>').addClass('pull-right').appendTo(clist);
});
```

Comment: You do have a repetition in your JSON. What happens with the 4 Search Engines that you have for example? one single li with the sum of counts, or 4 different li elements?

Comment: CHeck the question I made it clear and changed few contents

Comment: Ok, so it looks like from your snippet you are appending the li and the span to the ul.  From your desired output, it looks like you should be appending the span to the li.  And other than those two things, you're not doing anything with the count or pType from the elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the li elements mapping your input `teamDetails` array items, and append them to the ul container then

```js
const teamDetails=[ 
 { "pType" : "Search Engines", "count" : 5},
 { "pType" : "Content Server", "count" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Search Engines", "count" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Business", "count" : 1,},
 { "pType" : "Internet Services", "count" : 1},
];

const liElements = teamDetails.map(el => $(`<li>${el.pType}<span class="pull-right><strong><h5>${el.count}</h5></strong></span></li>`));
$('.list-unstyled').append(liElements);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Extracting from Array of Objects

- First add `<ul class="list-unstyled"></ul>` to the DOM using `.html()`.
- Use `.map()` on the outer array
- Use `Object.values()` on each object in the array
- Use `.map()` on the each of the object's values
- Used a fragment of the HTML string on alternating iterations
- After interpolating the values into each fragment, the result was an array of strings
- Convert the array of strings into a single string using `.join()`
- `.append()` the string to the empty list

---

### Demo

```js
var teamDetails = [{pType:"Search Engines",count:5},{pType: "Content Server",count: 1},{pType:"Business",count: 1},{pType: "Internet Services",count: 1}];

$('body').html(`<ul class="list-unstyled"></ul>`);

var result = teamDetails.map(function(item) {
  var obj = Object.values(item).map(function(val, idx) {
    if (idx % 2 === 0 || idx === 0) {
      var str = `<li><b class='tD A'>${val}  </b>`;
    } else {
      var str = `<b class='tD B'>${val}</b></li>`;
    }
    return str;
  });
  return obj;
});

var string = result.join(' ').replace(/,/g, '');

$('.list-unstyled').append(string);
```

```css
.tD {
  display: inline-block;
  font: 16px/1.2 Verdana;
}

.A {
  width: 15ch
}

.B {
  font: 700 20px/1 Consolas;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```